# Database Postgres - Cannot load the database

Tags: database, postgresql

I am new here. I am fighting with one problem like whole day and my friend told me, to check this site and make an topic about my problem. So I am here, tired of tryin and searching for resultion.
About the problem:
I want to start database on my postgres server by phpPgAdmin, but suddenly thanks to php(?) I am not allowed to.
The things looks like, that after loggin to phppgadmin without any problems, I am creating a database. Creation always goes fine, but the problem arrive just after that. I am not allowed to see what is inside and I am not even allowed to clic on the database, because the database cannot be loaded. It pops up some crazy error. 
The error looks like that:
"Error Loading database.php?subject=database&server=127.0.0.1%3A5432%3Aallow&action=tree&database=postgres (500: Internal Server Error)"

http://speedy.sh/Skp8j/postgres1.jpg
http://postimage.org/image/hc56f1qnb/full/

Seriously I am tired of it already, I really hope so, that you guys can help me.

with regards Dariss

Comment: Can you check your phperrors log file, or if you don't have one setup, your apache error log, and see if there is any useful log data in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the log file from apache. Tried to get an log file from php, but as far as I see, it do not generate any.
------nvm already :)

Comment: Nvm, fixed it. The issue was all about permissions. Log file nessecry thing :)